# How to assign value using another variables string data

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, assign

I want to assign value to new variable to use string value.

In code, I want to input list data to `tem_data` but this code input str data.

ex) `tem_data = set_tem_data`
Then how can I input `set_tem_data` value to `tem_data` just using `tem_data_name`

I tried about `locals()` or `exec()`, but not working

```
temp = 'set'
tem_name = temp + '_var_name'
set_tem_data = [0, 1, 2, 3]
tem_data_name = temp + '_tem_data'
locals()['tem_data'] = tem_data_name
print(tem_name)
```

I expect the output of `tem_data` is `[0, 1, 2, 3]`
but the result is `set_tem_data`...

Comment: What you're actually doing is string concatenation.

Comment: So what do you want to be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Because strings are immutable, there is nothing you can do to change a variable that will also change the string of a variable that was set equal to it.

I don't think what you're doing has much practical use, though.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you what I think about what you want:

```
import numpy as np
mylist = []
mylist.append(1)
mylist.append(2)
mylist.append(3)
mylist.append(4)
print(mylist)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
#conver to array:
myarray = np.asarray(mylist)
tem_data = myarray
print(tem_data)
[1 2 3 4]
```

or you can use mystrin += str(string)

```
a = "xx"
b = "yy"
x = a+str(" ")+b
print(x)
```

xx yy